# Live Mesh taskbar icon missing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, taskbar, windows-live-mesh

I just set up a new Windows 7 machine, went to the mesh.com to install the Live Mesh shoftware, and was able to use the website to view my desktop at home.  But on my home machine (running Windows Server 2008), Live Mesh installed a taskbar icon for Live Mesh, which allows me to launch a Mesh remote desktop session without visiting the mesh.com website.

But the Mesh taskbar icon is missing on my new Windows 7 machine-- I checked in the "hidden" section and the icon isn't there either. Also, looking in Task Manager there's no MOE.EXE running.

Any idea how to restore the taskbar icon on Win7?

Comment: ... Only a comment, Just want to check... Did you click the ^ Arrow to the left of the 3/4 default icons?

Comment: There's no MOE.EXE running and no taskbar icon for Mesh, even in the hidden section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MOE.exe is not running, then live mesh is not running. There could have been a problem with the installer that prevented it from finishing the install. As a good first step, check to see if the program shows up in the installed programs list in the control panel (Program and Features). If it is installed, time to check the registry for the autolaunch entry. I believe it is here:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run

There should be a key in there that points to "MOE.exe". If you then go to the install location, you can attempt to run the program manually.

I don't know if MOE would send errors to the event log, so it may be difficult to troubleshoot further. If all else fails, uninstall and reinstall the software. If it's an MSI file, you can use the "/log" switch to get detailed info on what is going on. I should warn you that the logging is not easy to follow for those who are unfamillier with it.

Hope this helps

[EDIT]

Live mesh installs some files to your user profile. I personally think that's weird but here is where it is:

C:\Users[User Name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Live Mesh

To install, you should just be able to go to [www.mesh.com](http://www.mesh.com) and add a device to your account. It will give you the option to re-download the software there.

Comment: Any idea where the install location is? I looked in Program Files, but didn't see anything related to Live Mesh, but may not be looking in the right place.  What I'd love to to is to re-install the Live Mesh software, but couldn't find a place to download it on the mesh.com site-- any ideas about that?

Comment: You should just be able to go to www.mesh.com to re-download.

Comment: hah. the problem seems obvious now in hindsight-- I didn't realize that I had to "add device" in order to download the mesh software. I kept looking for an "install" link before I gave up and assumed that the ActiveX control install was enough. Since I only wanted to use the new machine as a client, it didn't occur to me to "add device", and on the other machines I ran Live Mesh, I did "add device" first before trying to use the taskbar icon, so I didn't realize that the icon only showed up after addding the device. Thanks DoItknuckle for kicking me to realize the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the default windows 7 theme and restart live mesh, the icon should show. For some reason,the icon is not compatible with other color schemes in windows 7.